# Eclipse Luna (4.4.0) and Subclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I know there are tons of Eclipse/Subclipse questions out there regarding issues with javahl. I've been using Eclipse/Subclipse together for a long time without the javahl issues.

I'm now running into the same issue though.

I just recently upgraded to Java 7:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I also upgraded to Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 and installed Subclipse. But after creating a remote repository and trying to browse it in the SVN Repository Exploring perspective I see this in the Eclipse .log error log file:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.subversion.javahl.SVNClient
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.JhlClientAdapter.<init>(JhlClientAdapter.java:57)
    at org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.Activator.getAdapter(Activator.java:64)
    at org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.Activator.getClientAdapter(Activator.java:70)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNClientManager.getAdapter(SVNClientManager.java:127)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNClientManager.getSVNClient(SVNClientManager.java:94)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNProviderPlugin.getSVNClient(SVNProviderPlugin.java:462)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.repo.SVNRepositoryLocation.getSVNClient(SVNRepositoryLocation.java:257)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.RemoteFolder.getMembers(RemoteFolder.java:164)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.RemoteFolder.members(RemoteFolder.java:260)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.FetchMembersOperation.execute(FetchMembersOperation.java:41)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.SVNOperation.run(SVNOperation.java:90)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.repository.model.SVNRepositoryRootElement.fetchDeferredChildren(SVNRepositoryRootElement.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

See pic below to see the components I installed with Subclipse:

[image: Subclipse Installation]

Regarding the SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required), I have installed Subclipse both with and without this component selected and in both cases I see the same javahl.SVNClient error.

***How do I solve this?***

As an aside, I figured maybe I'd give Subversive a go. Subversive is not available in the Eclipse 4.4 udpates software site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4) so I tried the Eclipse Marketplace Client. Installing via Marketplace I get the following error:

```
The following solutions are not available: Subversive: SVN Team Provider 2.0
```

Does anyone have Eclipse and Subclipse or Subversive working? What steps do I need to take to get this working?

**UPDATE** attached is a screenshot of the empty SVN interface client dropdown.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have successfully installed subversive with eclipse Luna. See my answer(steps) below and let me know if u need anything else.

Answer (score 8):

I think that a solution can be found at Polarion website (developers of SVN connectors used by Subversive plugins)
http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php?utm_source=eclipse.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=subversive.

It says

> The Subversive Update Site is a part of Luna Update Site.
>
> To install:
> On main menu, choose Help > Install New Software. The available Software dialog appears.
> In the Work with list, select Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/. A list of software
> packages appears.
>
> Expand the Collaboration node, scroll the list and select Subversive features
>
> Check other options in the dialog as desired and click the Next button. The Install Details screen appears in the dialog.
>
> Click the Next button, accept the license and click Finish. Subversive will download and install.
>
> It is recommended to accept the option to restart Eclipse.
>
> http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/
> – [required] Subversive SVN Connectors
>
> http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/integrations/luna-site/
> – [optional] Subversive Integrations

Comment: still had the svn from last eclipse major. update to luna svn did the trick for me! thx.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose You don't have some library needed by jaha-hl. It depends on Your OS. Why don't You try SVN Kit instead of JavaHL? You can change provider in window -> preferences -> team -> subversion.

Comment: Just FYI I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5. Check my screenshot. I did install SVNKit. But when I go to change to SVN Kit, under 'SVN interface -> Client' There is a dropdown select list, but its empty. Nothing to select or change to.

Comment: I also am having trouble with Eclipse Luna. I didn't do a clean install, I just tried updating from Kepler. It had to fix a bunch of dependencies to go through the process, some of which had to do with Subversion. Now SVN isn't working for me, I get an empty drop-down for SVN Connectors.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) on OSX Mavericks using the same Subclipse version you are using.  In my case, the JavaHL library is installed via Homebrew.

I do not think it is related to your problem, but a difference in my environment is that I am using Java 8.  In hindsight it does not make sense but I have this recollection that Eclipse 4.4 said I had to upgrade Java for it to launch.  Maybe it said I needed at least Java 7 and I simply chose to install Java 8.  Do not remember.

I am a bit stumped ATM by your error because of the NoClassDef found.  That does not feel like the usual error you see when the problem is with your libraries.

What do you see in the preferences when you do Team > SVN?  The drop-down is empty?  That would imply the Eclipse plugins did not even load, because normally you would see the entry in the list with a message about (Not installed).  That you do not even see this seems like a bigger error is involved.

Not sure what to check, but I'd poke around the log and the Eclipse Installation Details screens to see if there is some problem with one or more of the plugins not being activated.  No explanation why that would happen though.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I've updated the original question with a screenshot of Eclipse SVN preferences where you can see the empty SVN interface client list is an empty dropdown. It's odd. This is a completely fresh install of Luna, I'm surprised I'm seeing issues already. Normally after installing several plugins and lots of use, crashes, etc...I might start seeing problems, but after a clean install this is strange.

Comment: The problems are all consistent with one or more of the plugins failing to load. I'd just keep digging into the Eclipse logs to see what you can spot. The fact that you do not even see items on the drop-down points to a very low-level problem where the code is just not loading at all.

Comment: Yeah...I couldn't find it. Figured a clean reinstall would be quicker which is what I did. Things are working now. Don't know what went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to install subversive and its connector is as below:

1. Go to Help->Install New software.
2. From the drop down list select "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna". Now some list should be populated.
3. In the populated list go to Collaborator->Subversive SVN Team Provider.
4. Click Finish.
   This is will install Subversive SVN Team Provider after restart of eclipse.

Then right click on empty are of Project Explorer and select import and then other. From the new menu select SVN-Project from SVN , this will ask for connector installation. Select desired connector and install it.

HTH

Comment: The question was about Subclipse, not Subversive - two different projects trying to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem:  "unable to load default svn client"

empty combo in 'preferences / team / svn'

I did like this to make works:

window > install new software >  http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x/

re-check all checkboxes, and go.
After restart, it was ok

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a new link or not, but you can just drag n drop the install icon from the [Eclipse Marketplace Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) site to your Eclipse Luna workspace to install it.